# App doesn't appear on iTunes file sharing

Tags: ios, iphone, testflight, file-sharing

I'm testing an app by means of TestFlight.

In the app I've enabled file sharing and when I connect my iPhone I can correctly see the app in iTunes/File sharing section.
The problem is that I've asked to one of the testers to send me some log files but he says he cannot see the app in iTunes/File sharing.

Is there any reason why I can see the app while the tester not?

Thanks,
Corrado

Answer (score -1, accepted):

One possible reason is that you do not have it installed successfully. You can try some other third party app to confirm whether it is well installed. If well installed, App will show on iTunes.

Comment: The user has installed the app by means of TestFlight and it is working as expected so I assume it's well installed. Anyway, at least now I know that the app should be present in iTunes even if in beta version and installed through TestFlight. Thx